# How can you select into variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, plpgsql

I have the following function:

```
Create or Replace Function someFunction([parameter1], [parameter2]) Returns Integer As $$
Declare
    someInt_ integer;
    totalRows_ integer;
Begin
    SELECT x INTO someInt_, COUNT(*) INTO totalRows_ 
    FROM [table]
    WHERE [some conditions];

    [more code]
End;
$$ Language 'plpgsql';
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  «count» is not a known variable
LINE 6:  SELECT x INTO someInt_, COUNT(*) INTO totalRows_ ...
                                 ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 181
```

How can I fix this?

I know a lot of data is missing, such as the return. It is because I have simplified it since the variables are in another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INTO` comes after all columns:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(*)
   INTO someInt_, totalRows_ 
FROM [table]
WHERE [some conditions];
```